# wdio clicks an element then throws exception saying element could not be located

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I have a strange issue with a test that was passing on Monday that is now failing. I keep getting the same error relating to the element not being located:

```
Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
at element(".component-search__cta") - click.js:12:17
at click(".component-search__cta") - errorHandler.js:112:39
```

The thing is, the element definitely was located and clicked by the code in my page object. The browser then redirects to a new page (as expected) but the test throws this spurious error.

Code couldn't be much simpler:

```
const Page = require('../../common/page_objects/page');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

class HomePage extends Page {

  static get elements() {
    return {
    searchBox: browser.element('.component-search__text'),
    searchButton: browser.element('.component-search__cta')
  };
}

  static search(query){
    this.elements.searchBox.waitForVisible();
    this.elements.searchBox.setValue(query);
    this.elements.searchButton.click();
  }
}

  this.When(/^I submit a search query "([^"]*)"$/, function(query) {
    HomePage.search(query);
  });
```

If I comment out `searchButton.click();` I don't get the error anymore, but the test will fail because the search button is no longer being clicked!

Comment: if discard obvious reasons(no element, need wait for element): may be it is multiple element('.component-search__cta') at page?

Comment: That locator only returns one element in the Chrome console. Though a better locator would be `button.component-search__cta`; changing it did not fix my problem. I also tried the waitForVisible method, but the weird thing about this issue is I can see the button being clicked every time.

Answer (score 0):

use the ‘xpath’ or  css selector  the frame will not found element or component If the selector is not sufficiently specific.
So try a more specific css selector like

span['class ="button"'] or //div/label/div

i hope this will help you to solve the problem.